Zapier: Slack Notification when a new file is uploaded to Google Drive
I have created a zap when a new file is uploaded to specific google drive, I will be notified in a slack channel.
The trigger is working fine but the issue is when someone uploads multiple files to triggers the event multiple times.
Let say if somebody uploaded 10 files at a time, the trigger will run 10 times and notify 10 times in slack. How can I limit this to 1 notification for all the files uploaded on a single day?
I tried any different actions but nothing is working

I would set up a daily cron to post a list of all newly uploaded files for any given day. Feel free to reach out if you need further help.

could you please show how to do it in your answer post instead of defering a full answer to more conversation?
